How to use conditions lists and a loop in C# to avoid long repetitive if-else statements
How can I use conditional lists in C# with a small loop to avoid long repetitive if-else block statements?
It is very easy to write a bunch of if-else statements for many different conditions that have an action that is very repetitive but with a sleight different value of variable to set.
Consider this example:
if (condition1 == 0 || condition2 == 0)
{
    variable1 = 1;
    variable2 = 100;
    Reason = "Status is this";
}
else if (condition3 == 1 || condition4 == 100)
{
    variable1 = 1;
    variable2 = 100;
    Reason = "Status is something else";
}
else if (condition5 == 2 || condition6 == 10)
{
    variable1 = 1;
    variable2 = 100;
    Reason = "Status is more";
}

Imagine that more conditions becomes necessary and you just end up adding more else-if with actions similar except the one variable is uniquely set.
How to write this optimized so that the code appears condensed (easy to read) and adding more conditions is simply adding a single line?
My suggestion is this:
var ConditionsList - new List<(bool Condition, string Reason)>
{
    (condition1 == 0 || condition2 == 0, "Status is this"),
    (condition3 == 1 || condition4 == 100, "Status is something else"),
    (condition5 == 2 || condition6 == 10, "Status is more")
};
foreach (var condition in ConditionsList)
{
    if(condition.Condition)
    {
        variable1 = 1;
        variable2 = 100;
        Reason = condition.Reason;
        break; //optional
    }
}

Expanding the conditions is simply adding another line in ConditionsList. Additionally adding the other variables into the list if they have unique or different values can be done. The code does not take so much space so it's easier to read and see in one go.
After implementing this once in my code, I was surprised to find it can be applied in many places with some variations.
Is there a better way to solve this problem or not?

What do you mean by "better"? You could use Func<bool> if you don't want to compute all the results ahead of time, but the metric "easy to read" is subjective.

Post an answer for Func for my question. Not sure how it can easily extend with more conditions.

I would say the break; in your suggested edit is not optional. Let's say you remove it. In your original example, the value of variable1, variable2 and Reason will be set a maximum of one time. In your suggested edit, those values would all be set up to three times (if all the conditions are true). Moreover, if condition1 == 0 || condition2 == 0 and condition5 == 2 || condition6 == 10 were both true, your original example would set Reason = "Status is this", whereas your suggested edit would result in Reason being set to "Status is more".

Repeatable code is prone to be extracted in method. Calling such method from 3 different if/else-if is what I would prefer.

If you have dozens of checks, then refactoring logic into fluent interface together with set of predefined conditonis/actions may improve readability: Conditions.IfA().OrB().DoC();

Pattern matching may help you. 1, 2, 3.

This might be a XY problem. I am curious to know what the variable1,2 and condition1-6 are in reality. Maybe there is a better way to structure all of them in a better way to begin with. E.g., the two condition-variables could be encapsulated in a class together with the comparison values and the Reason. But it is hard to tell without known more...

It's a function of how "complex" the conditions are. It varies from lists of enums, to lists of Func's and Action's.

I just want to leave a switch on a tuple because it may seem counter-intuitive if you don't know it is possible
var x = (0, 0);

switch(x)
{
    case (0,0): /*whatever*/;
        break;
}

In the example there is cond1, 2 etc. so I know it has to be changed, but maybe you can use the flavour.

An alternative (which I think is clearer - but this is subjective) is to use a local function to set variable1, variable2 and Reason:
void setReason(bool apply, string reason)
{
    variable1 =   1;
    variable2 = 100;
    Reason = reason;
}

if      (condition1 == 0 || condition2 ==   0) setReason("Status is this");
else if (condition3 == 1 || condition4 == 100) setReason("Status is something else");
else if (condition5 == 2 || condition6 ==  10) setReason("Status is more");

Note: I would generally end an if/else if cascade with an explicit else to handle the case where there were no matches, but since your OP doesn't do that I have omitted it from this answer.

I would use a list containing a tuple with a predicate and a record type that contains condition variables 1 to 6. With this approach, if you need to add more conditions anytime soon, you can simply add them into one list.
internal record ConditionRecord(int A, int B, int C, int D, int E, int F);

internal static class MessageLookup
{
    private static readonly List<(Predicate<ConditionRecord>, string)> s_messages = new()
    {
        ((c) => c.A == 0 || c.B == 0, "this"),
        ((c) => c.C == 1 || c.D == 100, "something else"),
        ((c) => c.E == 2 || c.F == 10, "more")
    };

    public static string? LookUpStatusByCondition(ConditionRecord rec)
    {
        (Predicate<ConditionRecord>, string)? firstResult = s_messages.FirstOrDefault(msg => msg.Item1(rec));
        return firstResult is null ? null : string.Concat("Status is ", firstResult.Value.Item2);
    }
}

Fiddle

There's not much point in using a dictionary if you're not using any of the dictionary features: no duplicated keys or looking up a record by key.

@gunr2171 Thanks for pointing that out. Edited the answer to use List instead.

I actually think there's hardly a worse solution than this:
var ConditionsList - new List<(bool Condition, string Reason)>
{
    (condition1 == 0 || condition2 == 0, "Status is this"),
    (condition3 == 1 || condition4 == 100, "Status is something else"),
    (condition5 == 2 || condition6 == 10, "Status is more")
};
foreach (var condition in ConditionsList)
{
    if(condition.Condition)
    {
        variable1 = 1;
        variable2 = 100;
        Reason = condition.Reason;
        break; //optional
    }
}


We allocate memory for a new List<> every time (what if this was in another loop?).

We evaluate ALL conditions when we initialize the list. So, we waste a bit of time there. For a true if / else if we don't have to continue doing that.

We can "refactor" the ConditionList outside of a possible loop and we get the conditions to capture just the initial state which won't change afterwards.

We have to remember which semantics we have in mind (else if vs successive ifs). Your mentioning of how optional the break; statement is which would differentiate between the two exemplifies how easy it is to misunderstand and/or misuse this pattern.

There is no catch-all, else here which is a very common scenario. I am sure we can add it but we have to remember how to use it.

It's gonna be more difficult to debug - where do you set a breakpoint?


I am sure there are others. Leave default control flow alone and if it gets out of hand, think about other ways to make things more "readable" - such as refactoring some logic into a local method as suggested in another answer.
That being said, I was also tempted to be a clever coder:
var condition1 = false;
var condition2 = true;

// local function
IEnumerable<(bool conditionEval, int result)> SwitchConditions() {
    yield return (condition1, 3);
    yield return (condition2, 4);
    yield return (true, 42); // default case
}

(_, var result) = SwitchConditions().First(x => x.conditionEval);
Console.WriteLine(result); // 4

condition2 = false;
(_, result) = SwitchConditions().First(x => x.conditionEval);
Console.WriteLine(result); // 42

condition1 = true;
(_, result) = SwitchConditions().First(x => x.conditionEval);
Console.WriteLine(result); // 3


You could think along the lines of the TryGetValue method in the Dictionary class,
e.g. by creating a local function tryGetStatus that returns a bool and provides an out parameter with the status text. If it returns true, the variable1, variable2 and Reason values are updated:
if (tryGetStatus(out var status))
{
    variable1 = 1;
    variable2 = 100;
    Reason = status;
}

The implementation of the local tryGetStatus function could take several different forms. One option is to create another local helper function which returns the status text, and then simply let tryGetStatus return whether a status text was provided:
bool tryGetStatus(out string status)
{
    status = getStatus();
    
    return status != null;
}

string getStatus()
{
    if (condition1 == 0 || condition2 == 0)   return "Status is this";
    if (condition3 == 1 || condition4 == 100) return "Status is something else";
    if (condition5 == 2 || condition6 == 10)  return "Status is more";
    return null;
}

